# My CSS Grid doesn't scale properly with content height-wise

Tags: html, css, css-grid, scaling

Okay, I'll try to make this pretty quick. I'm working on upgrading my website's looks as a fun project. I used tables before as my site layout, but I'm trying to use CSS Grid as I've learned a lot since then. I'm using a CSS grid of just 3 columns, the outer two act as margins and the center is for content. Whenever there is enough content to make the page scroll down, the margins don't grow with it. In fact, neither does the center, because when I scroll to the bottom after putting something below a tall image it just shows the background color of my container.

To make the question simpler, how do I make the off white parts of my page black like the rest of the margins?

Scrolled to middle of page: [Link to first picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OJBws.png)

Scrolled all the way to the bottom: [Link to second picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/51tKJ.png)

**I repeat, the off white color is not intentional, that's there because it's the color of the container. Everything that's the cream color should be black or gray!**

```css
body {
    margin: 0;
    width: 100vw;
    height: 100vh;
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    
}

  
.content {
    width: 70vw;
    height: 100vh;
    background-color: #252525;
}

.margin {
    width: 15vw;
    height: 100vh;
    background-color: #000000;
}

table{
    table-layout: fixed;
    border-collapse: collapse;
    width: 100%;
}

tr {
    vertical-align: top;
}

a {
    color: dodgerblue;
}

p {
    color: #45d163;
    font-size: 3.0vh;
    text-align: left;
    margin-left: 2.5vw;
    font-family: Arial, bold;
    font-weight: bold;
}

ol {
    margin-left: 3.5vw;
}
ul{
    
}
li{
    
}

.fixed {
    position: fixed;
}

.grid-container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 15% 70% 15%;
  background-color: #fceee3;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  min-width: 0;
  min-height: 100vh;

}
.grid-item {
  background-color: #000000;
  font-size: 5px;
  text-align: left;
  color: #f1f1f1;
  min-height: 100vh;
  margin-top: 0%;

  
}
 .grid-center {
  background-color: #252525;
  color: blue;
  font-size: 30vh;
  text-align: left;
  min-height: 100vh;
  margin-top: 0%;

}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" >
<!-- partial:index.partial.html -->
  
  <head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Keyboard Mechanic</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css"> </link>

    <style>

.header {
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #171615;
  padding: 1% 1%;
  width: 100%;
  position: fixed;
  height: 7%;
  
  
}

.header a {
  float: left;
  color: #f1f1f1;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 12px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 18px; 
  line-height: 25px;
  border-radius: 4px;
  
  width: max-content !important;
  margin-right: 10px;
 
}

.header a.active {
  background-color: dodgerblue;
  color: white;
  width: 8vw;
  margin-right: 10px;
  
}

.header a.logo {
  all: unset;
}

.login {
  background-color: dodgerblue;
  color: white;
  width: 8vw;
  margin-right: 10px;
}

.header a:hover {
  background-color: #ddd;
  color: black;
}



.header-right {
  float: right;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 100%) {
  .header a {
    float: none;
    display: block;
    text-align: left;
    
  }
 }
</style>

<style>
.wrapper {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 15% 70% 15%;
  grid-template-rows: 1fr;
  background-color: #fceee3;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100%;
  overflow: scroll;
  min-height: 100# !important;
 
}
.grid-item {
  background-color: #000000;
  font-size: 5px;
  text-align: left;
  color: #f1f1f1;
  margin-top: 0%;  
  height: auto;
  min-height: 100# !important;
  
}
 .grid-center {
  background-color: #252525;
  margin-top: 0%;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  min-height: 100# !important;

}


</style>


  </head>
    
  <body>  
      <div class="header">
          <a href="newLook.html" class="logo" > <img src="images/cornerlogo.png" height="50px"> </a>
          <div class="header-right">
          <a class="active" href="newLook.html">Home</a>
          <a class="active" href="games.html">Games</a>
          <a class="active" href="webprojects.html">Web Projects</a>
          <a class="login"  href="login.html">Login</a>
          <a href="contact.html">Contact</a>
          <a href="about.html" style="margin-right: 2vw;">About</a>
    
          </div>
       </div>
 
      <div class="wrapper"> 
        <div class="grid-item"> </div>
        
        <div class="grid-center"> 
            <p>Hello </p>
            <img style="width: 100%;" src="https://i.imgur.com/DvlV8Sh.png" />
            <p> Stuff outside the picture doesn't sit inside the center grid item, if it did, the background would be gray! </p>
        </div>
        
        <div class="grid-item"> </div>
      
      </div>
    
  </body>
  
</html>
<!-- partial -->
```

Comment: Please make your code into a runnable snippet that shows the problem. This may include having to give a full url to an image. Also what is 100# !important, should that be %? Make sure your snippet shows us the problem by running it yourself before publishing it.

Comment: Alright, I figured out how to link the image properly so you can get a better look. I also have the pictures linked at the top! The whole 100# thing is just a typo, I was trying many different things to get this to work so some code may not be relevant.

Comment: Thank you, that is much clearer. You've fixed the height so the content overflows. That is why it has a cream background. Do you want to set overflow-y: hidden so the user has to scroll to see the rest? Or do you want to let the height grow to whatever it needs to accommodate all the content?

Comment: I want the height to grow to the content yes!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could have done this with `flex`, To the best of my knowledge `grid` is not made for that purpose!

Here's an example made with `flex`

```css
body {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  margin: 0;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  background: #171615;
}

.header {
  /* If you don't want the header to be sticky on scroll remove these lines */
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
  /* If you don't want the header to be sticky on scroll remove these lines */
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-between;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  width: 100%;
  background: #171615;
}

.header-logo {
  height: 55px;
}

.logo {
  height: 100%;
  width: 135px;
  object-fit: cover;
}

.header-menu {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
}

.header-menu a {
  color: #f1f1f1;
  padding: 12px;
  text-decoration: none;
  border-radius: 4px;
  margin-right: 8px;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

.header a.active {
  background: dodgerblue;
}

.login {
  background-color: dodgerblue;
}

.header-menu a:hover {
  background-color: #ddd;
  color: black;
}

.wrapper {
  width: 70%;
  color: white;
}


/* you can remove this part */

.white-space {
  display: flex;
  height: 800px;
  font-size: 3rem;
  background: darkgray;
}


/* you can remove this part */
```

```html
<div class="header">
  <div class="header-logo">
    <a href="#"><img class="logo" src="https://via.placeholder.com/135x55" alt="Logo" /></a>
  </div>
  <div class="header-menu">
    <a class="active" href="#">Home</a>
    <a class="active" href="#">Games</a>
    <a class="active" href="#">Web Projects</a>
    <a class="login" href="#">Login</a>
    <a href="#">Contact</a>
    <a href="#">About</a>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="wrapper">
  <!-- put your content here -->
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ac ut consequat semper viverra. Eget nunc scelerisque viverra mauris in aliquam sem fringilla ut.</p>
  <div class="white-space">
    <h2 style="margin: auto">White Space</h2>
  </div>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ac ut consequat semper viverra. Eget nunc scelerisque viverra mauris in aliquam sem fringilla ut.</p>
  <!-- put your content here -->
</div>
```

Updated:
added custom height to the header

```css
body {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  margin: 0;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  background: #171615;
}

.header {
  /* If you don't want the header to be sticky on scroll remove these lines */
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
  /* If you don't want the header to be sticky on scroll remove these lines */
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-between;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  width: 100%;
  background: #171615;
}

.header-logo {
  height: 55px;
}

.logo {
  height: 100%;
  width: 135px;
  object-fit: cover;
}

.header-menu {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
  height: 100px;
  align-items: center;
}

.header-menu a {
  color: #f1f1f1;
  padding: 12px;
  text-decoration: none;
  border-radius: 4px;
  margin-right: 8px;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

.header a.active {
  background: dodgerblue;
}

.login {
  background-color: dodgerblue;
}

.header-menu a:hover {
  background-color: #ddd;
  color: black;
}

.wrapper {
  width: 70%;
  color: white;
}


/* you can remove this part */

.white-space {
  display: flex;
  height: 800px;
  font-size: 3rem;
  background: darkgray;
}


/* you can remove this part */
```

```html
<div class="header">
  <div class="header-logo">
    <a href="#"><img class="logo" src="https://via.placeholder.com/135x55" alt="Logo" /></a>
  </div>
  <div class="header-menu">
    <a class="active" href="#">Home</a>
    <a class="active" href="#">Games</a>
    <a class="active" href="#">Web Projects</a>
    <a class="login" href="#">Login</a>
    <a href="#">Contact</a>
    <a href="#">About</a>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="wrapper">
  <!-- put your content here -->
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ac ut consequat semper viverra. Eget nunc scelerisque viverra mauris in aliquam sem fringilla ut.</p>
  <div class="white-space">
    <h2 style="margin: auto">White Space</h2>
  </div>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ac ut consequat semper viverra. Eget nunc scelerisque viverra mauris in aliquam sem fringilla ut.</p>
  <!-- put your content here -->
</div>
```

Comment: This was exactly the fix I was looking for! I need to edit it some, but the concept is very clear to me now. I couldn't tell you how much of a damper this was putting on this project, I can't thank you enough!

Comment: you can specify it in `.header-menu{height:100px;}`, After adding height If the size of the links is messed up, add this line to `.header-menu{align-items: center;}`. I'll also update the answer and add another example to show you the result

Comment: I just deleted the comment because I realized it was kind of  dumb question, I ended up giving .header{height: 12%;}. Thank you for answering anyways, that information is useful for something else I had in mind too.

Comment: no problem, any time, good luck :)

Answer (score 0):

Remove the min-height for .grid-center and .grid-item:

```
.grid-item {
  background-color: #000000;
  font-size: 5px;
  text-align: left;
  color: #f1f1f1;
  margin-top: 0%;
}
.grid-center {
  background-color: #252525;
  color: blue;
  font-size: 30vh;
  text-align: left;
  margin-top: 0%;
}
```

Comment: This did not work for me personally, I had fiddled with that stuff numerous times before